# Converting pie chart to bar chart in pentaho dynamically

Tags: jquery, pentaho, pentaho-cde

I am using Pentaho 5.0.1 CE. My requirement is to convert one type of chart(dashboard) into another,

Ex: Pie Chart to Bar Chart when user drop an image in existing chart.

I am new to Pentaho. I have gone through [this](http://pentaho-bi-suite.blogspot.in/2014/07/protovis-sunburst-chart-example-in.html) but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't switch the type of chart on the fly. The solution is creating multiple charts, one of each type and enabling/disabling the charts depending on a parameter value with something like this on the preExec of the components:

```
function(){
return chartType == "Pie"
}
```

If the chartType variable is Pie preExec returns true and the component gets executed. Otherwise it's not.

Comment: Hi @nsousa, Thanks for the quick reply. I already implemented what you have suggested.As you said above that chart can't be change on fly. Did you read this anywhere or it's your experience. Don't take me wrong, just making sure that there is no possibility for the said scenario.

Comment: I was part of the team that developed it, and worked there for about 2 years.